# Specifying packet length with scapy

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I'm trying to send a specific packet size (100 bytes) with `scapy` but cant seem to get it.

I'm using this to start.

```
sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/TCP(dport=443))
```

Looking at the docs / help I cant tell if I can use `PacketLenField` to specify the length of the packet. I can do it with NMAP & NSE but would like to do it outside of NMAP.

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add on the required number of bytes as a String when crafting the packet e.g.:

```
payload = 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
pkt = Ether() / IP() / TCP() / payload
```

will work. You just need to adjust the length of the payload as you require.

Answer (score 2):

Scapy's `Raw()` function populates the payload of the packet.  If you know your header size, you only need to fill in the remaining bytes with random data.

You can use `RandString()` to generate random padding.  The following command sends a packet of length 100 (and listens for a response):

`sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/TCP(dport=443)/Raw(RandString(size=72))`

Comment: RandString()? Where is that exactly?

Comment: In scapy.utils: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.utils.html#

Answer (score 1):

You may use `inet.Padding()` from `scapy` library:

```
packet = IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/TCP(dport=443)

if len(packet)<100:
    #"\x00" is a single zero byte
    myString = "\x00"*(100 - len(packet))
    packet = packet/inet.Padding(myString)
```